# Search Google for certain CMS platforms

Tags: search

I would like to use Google to search for certain platforms. The platform I want to search for today is Big Commerce. I just want a list of websites that are using Big Commerce.

I have found a common ground between bigcommerce sites. Most if not all use Bigcommerce for the nameservers. They also have this script in their head tags http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com

I have searched for "http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com" but don't get many bigcommerce sites. How can set a search query within google to find sites that use Bigcommerce for nameservers or have http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com within their head tags?

Comment: I can't seem to find out how to search for stuff within the head tags. Maybe just knowing this will help me figure out the search query I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiment with search queries such as:

- inurl:http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com
- inanchor:http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com
- fashion inurl:http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com

Can combine inurl: or inanchor:, e.g.,

- inurl:http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com OR inanchor:http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com
- inurl:http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com | inurl:http://cdn.bigcommerce.com

where OR and | are synonymous for search for either this or that and can be contained within parentheses if your queries get really complicated, e.g., (this OR that) ("dog house*" | catbird")